# TFS Build fails after trying to associate the changesets with build

Tags: tfs, msbuild

When a second build with exiting build definition is queued, it fails with the error **Method not found: GetQueryXml**. The only workaround is to clone to a new build and queue that.

Is there any way to solve this issue ? Or if this build step can be skipped ?

```
Associate the changesets that occurred since the last good build00:00:03
Analyzing labels DevBuild_18.02.16.3 and DevBuild_18.02.21.1.
Changeset '9361' was included in this build.
Changeset '9362' was included in this build.
Changeset '9363' was included in this build.
Changeset '9366' was included in this build.
 Exception Message: **Method not found**: 'System.Xml.XmlElement Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Internals.WiqlAdapter.**GetQueryXml**(System.String, System.Collections.IDictionary, Boolean, Boolean)'. (type MissingMethodException) 

Exception Stack Trace: Server stack trace: at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Query.Initialize(WorkItemStore store, String wiql, IDictionary context, Int32[] ids, Int32[] revs, Boolean dayPrecision) at 
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Query..ctor(WorkItemStore store, String wiql) at 
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.WitQueryWorkItems.RunCommand(WorkItemStore workItemStore, IEnumerable`1 ids, IEnumerable`1 fields, Int32 pageSize, Boolean includeParentWorkItems) at 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs) at 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink) Exception rethrown at [0]: at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase) at 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed, MessageData& msgData) at System.Func`6.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.WitQueryWorkItems.EndExecute(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result) at System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity`1.System.Activities.IAsyncCodeActivity.FinishExecution(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result) at System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityData.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityWorkItem.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
```

Comment: Which build are you using the old XAML build or new vNext build? Could you explain more clear about this `When a second build with exiting build definition is queued,`  What' the mean of exiting build definition? Sorry, not totally got your point.

Comment: I am using old XAML build. I cannot use the same build twice, as it results in this error. Creating a new build definition everytime means it does not look for changesets to link and hence error does not come.

Comment: The build step could be skipped, if you use your customize build template. Which build template are you using? Are you using the default one(TfvcTemplate.12.xaml or GitTemplate.12.xaml)?  And what's the result if you queue the new created build definition twice? Did the issue only occurs on that specific build definition or all the new created build definition? If the issue occurs on all new created build definition, guess the issue should related to your build template.

Comment: I am using TfvcTemplate.12.xaml I edited it to remove the mtba:AssociateChanges element  Thanks Patrick

Comment: I edited TfvcTemplate.12.xaml to remove the mtba:AssociateChanges element and that did the trick for me. Thanks for guiding me to it Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue should related to XAML build template. If you are using the default one (TfvcTemplate.12.xaml or GitTemplate.12.xaml),  you could customize the template and **remove the corresponding activity**. How to please refer:  [Customize your build process template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551(v=vs.120).aspx).

> *Update from OP:* I edited TfvcTemplate.12.xaml to remove the
>   **mtba:AssociateChanges** element and that did the trick for me.